Convert Blob to wav file in js to send it in the body of a POST request
I'm working on a project where I need to send an audio file through a form-data body in a POST request.
But the audio file comes from the browser, recording my microphone and giving me a blob of the record.
I need to convert this blob to a wav/mp3 file and send it to my request.
Here is the blob I get :
raw code of the blob
So, how can I properly convert it to an audio file and send it in a form-data body in my fetch function ?
Thanks a lot !
I tried to parse the blob, to stringify it, but nothing worked for me.

The data in the blob is a "wav file" (i.e. it has content-type "audio/wav"), so you can just post it directly without any clientside conversions. Why do you want to send it as form-data? You can post binary data using fetch... You can also encode a blob into form-data. Work through this and come back with a question that has specific code and specific errors / failures. You'll have a much more positive SO experience if you invest more into your question.
